# customize swipe delete button in swift4

Tags: ios, ios11, swift4

I have customize Swipe delete button till swift3 [ios 9]. 
 
I have tried this code for ios 9 in swift3

```
func setSwipeDeletebutton(cell : UITableViewCell, BackView : UIView) {

    //Customize Delete button
    for subview in cell.subviews {
        subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        for sub in subview.subviews {

            if String(describing: sub).range(of: "UITableViewCellActionButton") != nil {
                sub.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

                var newframe = sub.frame
                newframe.size.height = BackView.frame.size.height
                sub.frame = newframe

                sub.SetUpView()

                for view in sub.subviews {

                    if String(describing: view).range(of: "UIButtonLabel") != nil {

                        if let label = view as? UILabel {

                            label.textColor = SharedInstance.hexStringToUIColor(hex: Color.TodayActivityColor.Type_LEAVE)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, as a change in ios 11, I can not customize swipe delete button using this code. 
I have tried to set image as swipe delete button, but it's not set properly because I also want shadow to that delete button.
Can anyone suggest that how can I customize the swipe delete button using swift4?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: with this subview concept i can not change swipe delete button in swift4. like i want delete button background color white with shadow effect and its font color in red in swift4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing subviews by using:

`String(describing: sub).range(of: "UITableViewCellActionButton")`

And

`String(describing: view).range(of: "UIButtonLabel")`

*This is not advisable by apple.*

However, to debug this issue open your view hierarchy while the table view row action / drawer is open.

[image: access view hierarchy debugging]

You should see the view you wish to alter, in the hierarchy.

[image: access view hierarchy for tableview]

Then change your Strings as required:

`String(describing: sub).range(of: "UISwipeActionPullView")`

`UISwipeActionPullView` may not be what you need but the concept is the same.